# Import module in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using python flask. I want to import a module from a different directory.

I have file called `hello.py`

PATH = project/app/hello.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

I have another file called `tables.py`

PATH = project/db/migration/tables.py

```
app.config("Database")
```

So, I need to import app from hello.py

```
from app.hello import app
app.config("Database")
```

I am executing the script `tables.py` like,

```
cd project/db/migration
python3 tables.py
```

It is saying `no module found app.hello`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `__init__.py` in the `app` folder to make it become a [Python package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), then you can import a module inside it with `from app.hello import app`. The file structure may like this:

```
app / 
    | __init__.py
    | hello.py
```

P.S. The `__init__.py`'s content can be empty.